# How to open web-site from windows-forms using post-request?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, post

I'm writting winforms applcation, c#. I want to send post-request to website and let it open in browser, as I used web-site to load some files using the form. I know about WebRequest and so on, and I know how to send request and get response without opening browser at all. But how to such a thing?

upd : really it doesn't matter that it is winforms, it may be also just console application

Answer (score -2):

Use the win form browser control